# Rails + Bootstrap Tags Input + typeahead

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js

I'm trying to set up this feature on my little project in rails: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

But I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I dropped jquery, bootstrap-tagsinput and typeahead.bundle files into my app/assets/javascript, but I still can't get it to work.

To my form I added:

```
<input type="text" data-role="tagsinput" />
<%= javascript_tag do %>
$('input').tagsinput({
  typeahead: {
    source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
  }
});
<% end %>
```

and a citynames.json to my app/assets folder, as well as added

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

to the top, but while tags input itself kinda works, I can't get typeahead to work or add freeInput: false option and get that one to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. download latest [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://codeload.github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/zip/latest)
2. get `bootstrap-tagsinput.css` from `/src` and put to `/assets/stylesheets/`.
3. Rename `bootstrap-tagsinput.css` to `bootstrap-tagsinput.scss` if you use scss
4. In applications.scss `@import 'bootstrap-tagsinput'` or `require`
5. get `bootstrap-tagsinput.js` from `/src` and put to `/assets/javascript/`
6. in `assets/javascript/application.js` require your js `=//require bootstrap-tagsinput`

---

```
prefetch: {
    url: 'assets/citynames.json',
    filter: function(list) {
      return $.map(list, function(cityname) {
        return { name: cityname }; });
    }
  }
```

`url: 'assets/citynames.json'` - this will not work. you can provide citinames from controller or put this file in public and after that you can get this json from public folder `root_url/folder/citinames.json.`

Comment: Trying it right now. About public - I didn't figure out yet completely how to point route to files in there using relative addressing. If file is just in public folder I have in project root, will it be "../public/citinames.json"?

Comment: Alright, seems bootstrap plugin works now! Still didn't get typeahead to work though.

Comment: if you put a file to `/public/file.*` that will be accessible from url: `http://your_url/file.*`

Comment: Hmm, no way to use relative addressing? I want to be able to test it on my dev environment (which is basically on localhost) and on live (which has it's own url). EDIT: can I alternatively pass the possible tags as array just inside my view .erb file?

Comment: if you put `citynames.json` to `public` then you can get this json from `http://localhost:3000/citynames.json`

Comment: Tried it, still seems that typeahead not working (prompt when entering text doesn't come up)

Comment: yes, you can pass the tags from view  like this. `<%=  javascript_tag do %> var citynames = "#{@citynames}" <% end %>` and @citinames you can initialize in viw or from controller action

Comment: Will try to use var method and see if typeahead starts working, will update post when done

Comment: ok, I used <%= javascript_tag do %>
 $('input').tagsinput({
   typeahead: {
  source: ['Amsterdam', 'Washington', 'Sydney', 'Beijing', 'Cairo']
   }
 });
 <% end %>  (updated main post too) but it seems to still not function.

Comment: (took it from example on bootstrap tags input page)

Comment: you installed typehead.js ?

Comment: I copied it from their website to same assets/javascript folder. Is that enough? And added //= require typeahead.bundle to application.js

Comment: There is a lot of things wich can provide errors. Maybe if you upload your project to github i will try to help

Comment: Updated. I'm trying to implement that field in views/articles/_form.erb instead of current Keywords field with select.

Comment: Ok, trying to understand changes, but ran into a problem: it seems to be working fine with test example, but when I changed code to use different keywords for taginput it still keeps using cities and doesn't pick words I put in controller. Any idea why that's happening? Updated github.